# how to generate numbers for pagination?

Tags: python

I made a function that returns the number displayed for pagination. I want to get something like this (parentheses is the only show where the active site):

if pages < 10

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

if pages > 10

```
1 2 3 ... 20 [30] 40 ... 78 79 80
```

where [30] is active page. If active page < 3

```
1 2 [3] 4 ... 20 30 40 ... 78 79 80
```

etc. My code:

```
    count_all - number of all items
    items_on_page - items displayed on one page
    page - current page

    countpages = int(float(count_all+(items_on_page-1))/float(items_on_page))
    linkitems = 10

    if countpages > (linkitems-1):
        countpagesstr = list()
        for i in range(1,int(float(linkitems+(2))/float(3))):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]

        countpagesstr += ['...']
        sr = int(countpages/2)
        for i in range(sr-1, sr+1):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]

        countpagesstr += ['...']
        for i in range(countpages-3, countpages):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]
    else:
        cp = list()
        for c in range(1,countpages+1):
            cp.append(str(c))
        countpagesstr = cp

    return countpagesstr
```

How to do it better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't run as written. It needs a function definition.
2. Your design needs work. Suppose the current page is 30 and the list of pages says "... 20 [30] 40 ..." as in your example. How do I get to page 29 or page 31? It doesn't look as if these page numbers will ever appear in the list.

   The more usual design is to always show a small number of pages at the beginning and end, and a small number of pages adjacent to the current page. So that the list of pages would look more like "1 2 3 ... 28 29 [30] 31 32 ... 78 79 80".
3. The expression

   ```
   int(float(count_all+(items_on_page-1))/float(items_on_page))
   ```

   is unnecessarily complex. You can use Python's floor division operator (`//`) to achieve the same thing without converting to floats and back again:

   ```
   (count_all + items_on_page - 1) // items_on_page
   ```
4. Your variables are poorly and unsystematically named. `count_all`, for example. All what? Or `countpagesstr`, which sounds like it might be a string, but is in fact a list. You use underscores in some cases (`count_all`) but not in others (`countpages`).
5. It is easiest conceptually to separate the two steps of *deciding which page numbers to show* and *showing them in order with ellipses*.

   In the code below I build the set of the page numbers from the first three pages, the five pages around the current page, and the last three pages. I use Python's sets so that I can take this union without having to worry about duplicate page numbers.

   ```
   def abbreviated_pages(n, page):
       """
       Return a string containing the list of numbers from 1 to `n`, with
       `page` indicated, and abbreviated with ellipses if too long.

       >>> abbreviated_pages(5, 3)
       '1 2 [3] 4 5'
       >>> abbreviated_pages(10, 10)
       '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 [10]'
       >>> abbreviated_pages(20, 1)
       '[1] 2 3 ... 18 19 20'
       >>> abbreviated_pages(80, 30)
       '1 2 3 ... 28 29 [30] 31 32 ... 78 79 80'
       """
       assert(0 < n)
       assert(0 < page <= n)

       # Build set of pages to display
       if n <= 10:
           pages = set(range(1, n + 1))
       else:
           pages = (set(range(1, 4))
                    | set(range(max(1, page - 2), min(page + 3, n + 1)))
                    | set(range(n - 2, n + 1)))

       # Display pages in order with ellipses
       def display():
           last_page = 0
           for p in sorted(pages):
               if p != last_page + 1: yield '...'
               yield ('[{0}]' if p == page else '{0}').format(p)
               last_page = p

       return ' '.join(display())
   ```